# Extension Plugin compilation for Android fails due qmldir not found

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.3

I have QML extention plagin created by Qt Creator wizard. When I try to compile it for Android, compilation fails with message:

> mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'F:/work/app-project/build-app-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1-Debug/extention'
>   mingw32-make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'F:\work\app-project\build-app-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1-Debug\extention\qmldir', needed by 'libextention.so'.  Stop.

What is wrong with extention `.pro` file? Host OS - Windows 7, Qt - 5.3.1

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = extention
QT += qml quick declarative
CONFIG += qt plugin

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = com.example.extention

# Input
SOURCES += \
    Plugin.cpp \
    extention.cpp

HEADERS += \
    Plugin.h \
    extention.h


OTHER_FILES = qmldir

!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    copy_qmldir.target = $$OUT_PWD/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.depends = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.commands = $(COPY_FILE) \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.depends, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\" \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.target, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\"
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copy_qmldir
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$copy_qmldir.target
}

qmldir.files = qmldir
unix {
    installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \\., /)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    target.path = $$installPath
    INSTALLS += target qmldir
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have the exact same problem, but nobody seems to have answered this question. Can you post a solution as an answer here if you have one ?

Comment: There is a solution to build binaries into source dir, not to different dir. Sorry, I forget exact terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Use [QRC](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html) instead of copying .qml-files to your build directory. Qt will handle all system-dependent problems for you.